# Ways of implementing an in app pin lock feature

Tags: android, performance

I already have a pin lock feature implemented in the application. The requirement is to show the pin lock on app launch (that is ok), and when the app is coming from the background. Unfortunately it seems my current implementation is not enough.
The current implementation using a base activity where i have implemented a threshold based pin lock feature. In the activity's onPause i save the current time, and in the onResume i check the difference between the saved and the current time, and if it is grater then 1 sec then i push the pin activity on top. It is working as expected, but the threshold is too big.

I have tried with 500ms for example, but my problem  is i can't get lower threshold values because on some older/slower devices the pin screen will pop up randomly between to activity (because of the 500ms) transition.

I would like to ask if somebody have other ideas how to implement a not threshold base pin feature. I don't really want a service to run in the background and constantly checking if the app is in the foreground, etc.

Any advise ?
Thanks

Comment: Your qeustion is about reliably recognizing that an Activity was off screen, right? Can you explain a bit more in detail when exactly the pin lock should be activated and when not? What should happen in case of a user presses home, back, changes to another app, comes back, the screen gets locked, ...

Answer (score 0):

Why would you even need the threshold values, if you simply force the pinlock upon onResume() or onPause() it should work as intended.

Comment: Good question. I guess, that the pin lock gets accidentally activated e.g. when the screen is rotated. But lets see what @Alex answers.

Comment: It is need because if there is no threshold then on every activity start the pinlock will appear even if the user tap on a button, or menu item for example to start the Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a pin lock feature as follows:

- Implement the `Activity.onUserLeaveHint()` and `onBackPressed()` method to differentiate if the following `onResume()` is because of a user interaction or e.g. because of a rotation of the device. Save the flag in the applications cache.
- Activate the pin lock (and start the corresponding dialog) in `onResume()` only if `onUserLeaveHint()` or `onBackPressed()` was called before (read from application cache) or the cache does not exist (first run)
- A threshold might be useful, depending on your application. But that should be like "re-enter your pin after 10 minutes of inactivity"

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working as i imagined or it is in the documentation. I have played with this method a little bit, but it get called even when i start a new activity, not get called when i press the back button and get back to the app drawer

Comment: Android kind of gives you a puzzle in this area. To react on the back key, you additionally need to override `onBackPressed()`. The third method around this topic `onUserInteraction()` is not very useful here as it reacts, when the user interacts somehow with the device, but you cannot be sure, that the interaction is the reason for a call to `onPause()`.